# Bootstrap raw is not working in project made in Yii2. Posts intended to be displayed from left to right

Tags: html, css

I wanted to display posts order by left to right.I tried to use bootstrap raw however I wasn't able to reach my targer. Thus,posts are being displayed from top to bottom.Below is my code:

```
       <div class="hl1"></div>
        <h2>Yangiliklar</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span3">
<div class="thumb4"><?php foreach(\app\models\Posts::find()->all() as $model){?> 
                    <div class="thumbnail clearfix">
   <figure><img src="uploads/<?=$model->image?>"  style="width:166px;height:110px" alt=""></figure>

      <div class="caption">
 <h5><a href="<?=\yii\helpers\Url::to(['post/view','id'=>$model->id]) ?>" style="color: blue;">  <?=$model->title?></a>
                            </h5>
<p>     <?= mb_substr($model->description, 0, 150); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div><?php }?>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div> 

            </div>
```

Comment: What are the properties of `span3`? AFAIK the bootstrap column classes are written as `col-3` for example.

Comment: As it sits I'm not sure what you're asking.